# How can I decrypt a Monero wallet to get a private key?

Tags: wallet-recovery

I have lost password & secret seed phrase to my monero wallet, but I have the .keys file with me.

I have generated a hash of my .keys file but how can I decrypt it to a human readable format?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to brute force the wallet password. It's not going to be super fast, since the encryption key is generated from the password you lost using Cryptonight as a KDF, which will limit the number of keys you generate to a few thousand per second. The encryption used is chacha8 for older wallets and chacha20 for newer wallets. I believe there is software which automates that brute forcing but I don't have a link nor a name.