# Decrypt Monero wallet from .keys file

Tags: wallet-recovery, wallet, encryption, keys-file

I am interested in how Monero encrypts the wallets. I found some resources and followed the source code of Monero:

[How to decrypt a wallet](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/13207/how-to-decrypt-a-wallet)

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/67d190ce7c33602b6a3b804f633ee1ddb7fbb4a1/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp

I know the encryption scheme is:

```
key = cryptonight.cn_slow_hash('MyPhrase', 0, 0, 0) // kfd_round = 1
iv = random(8) // 8 Bytes of IV
cipher = ChaCha20(msg, key, IV)
write_bytes('wallet.keys', IV || cipher)
```

So I tried to decrypt the wallet like this (in Python with `pycryptonight` and `pycryptodome`):

```
>>> import pycryptonight as pycy
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import ChaCha20
>>> with open('wallet.keys', 'rb') as f:
...   file = f.read()
...
>>> key = pycy.cn_slow_hash(b'MyWalletPwd')
>>> IV = file[:8]
>>> encrypted = file[8:]
>>> cipher = ChaCha20.new(key=key, nonce=IV)
>>> msg = cipher.decrypt(encrypted)
>>> msg[:20]
b"'\x1fS\xe5\xb0\xb4\xbfZ\x00O\x91\xae^\xd9\x82i*\xa7%6"
```

This [issue](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/issues/3088#issuecomment-791043574) said the result should be like `{"key_data":"...`, so what I got seems incorrect. I checked cryptonight results with examples from [Monero test dir](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/67d190ce7c33602b6a3b804f633ee1ddb7fbb4a1/tests/hash/tests-slow.txt) and they all matched.

I am using the Monero client (`win-x64-v0.18.2.2`) downloaded on Aug. 30, 2023, so it should be ChaCha20 not ChaCha8. I also tried ChaCha20-Poly1305, and still couldn't get the correct result.

Could anyone tell me what went wrong? Thanks a lot.